# 3g Dongle switches to a weird product ID

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt, lsusb

I am using a TP-Link MA 260 dongle plugged into an OpenWrt device. The dongles has two modes:

**USB mode:** `vendor=0x2357 product=0xf000`

**Modem mode:** `vendor=0x2357 product=0x9000`

Both work as expected in their respective modes and I use `usb_modeswitch` to switch between the two. This is the full command to switch to modem mode:

```
usb_modeswitch -v 2357 -p f000 -V 2357 -P 9000 -W -I -n -M '5553424312345678000000000000061e000000000000000000000000000000' -2 '5553424312345678000000000000061b000000020000000000000000000000'
```

**My problem is** that occasionally, the modem switches to `product=0x900e` and I have no idea what that is. Does anyone know what it means and how I can switch back from the mode incase it happens? Brownie points if someone can really explain why it occurs and whether or not it's random.

Comment: Which distro are you using? usb_modeswitch has built-in support for this device so you shouldn't have to run this command manually. Also, have you tried running this command after it switches to 900e (after changing the -p parameter)?

Comment: I am using the latest Attitude Adjustment and this "openwrt-ar71xx-generic-tl-mr3020-v1-squashfs-factory" package. I have not tried rerunning the command without the -p (I did not think of doing it and it's hard to debug given that I do not know how to get it into 900e mode.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this happens occasionally, and it is just a matter of removing and re-inserting the dongle, and then it shows the right id.

I have had situations where I have run usb_modeswitch several times, just to realize that the switch has been done "sort of".
In these cases, just remove and reinsert the stick and it gets the right id.

Why it is happening? I have no idea whatsoever, to me, it seems like a bug in the dongle. It is supposed to initialize as a mass storage device under windows, but either there is a third option that is triggered sometimes or it is just a plain bug.

Comment: I should also add a shameless plug that I have written an article on getting an MA 260 working with a RT-N66U router, not DD-WRT, but similar:
http://www.optimalbpm.se/wiki/index.php/ASUS_RT-N66U_TP-Link_MA260